# Best way to retrieve the objects from variable arguments

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an interface:

```
public interface Animal
{
   public Object info(Object ... o);
}
```

One of it's implementation :

```
public class Cat implements Animal
{
   public Object info(Object ... o)
   {
     //Extracting the information passed
     String a1 = (String)o[0];
     int b1 = (int)o[1];
     boolean c1 = (boolean)o[2];
   }
}
```

The datatype of `a`, `b` and `c` is always `String`, `int` and `boolean` respectively from place where the `info` method of `Cat` is called.

My question was that is their some neater way of extracting these objects and typecasting into the original form ?

Following solution would have been best but it cannot be implemented in java :

```
public class Cat implements Animal
{
  public Object info(String a1, int b1, boolean c1)
  {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be good to provide some more context, for example: What is the `info` method supposed to do and how is it called? A solution might be to make `Animal` a generic type, e.g. `Animal<T>` and then define the method as `info(T)`. Then you could make subclass specific container classes such as `CatInfoData` which stores a `String`, an `int` and a `boolean` and then define `Cat` as `Cat implements Animal<CatInfoData>`.